# getting deadlock for 2 instances of same transaction with serializable isolation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, innodb

I have a Spring Transaction that's annotated with

```
isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE
```

The transaction has the following steps:

```
1)Read from MySQL Tables 1, 2[Both InnoDB engine based]
2)Write into Table 1
3)Write into Table 2
```

Now when i ran two instances of the same transaction in almost parallel multiple times, i got two responses :

```
1)Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
2)Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The deadlock situation seems particularly interesting(as per deadlock details from innoDb Engine) :

Txn 1 is stuck at Step 2 waiting for a lock of mode 'S' on an index of table T1.

Txn 2 is stuck at Step 3 , holding lock of mode 'X' on the same index as above & with the same details(hex. ids mentioned as in above lock) & is waiting for a 'X'  mode lock on table T2.

Finally, Txn1 gets rolled back.

I feel that some index range locking is causing the deadlock, but would like to understand it how can it happen?

Also, if this is how isolation works(allowing txns to run in parallel & rolling back one of them), why is the Lock Wait timeout situation manifesting?

Answer (score 0):

The read needs `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.

If that does not suffice, please show us the sql statements from `BEGIN` to `COMMIT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.